# Linux Sudo Without Password Prompt

Tags: sudo, startup, command

I want to run a bash command at startup (~/.config/autostart/myCommand.desktop) that requires sudo, but rather than it prompting me every time, I would like to include the password in the command, something like:

`sudo --some-flag [PASSWORD] [command]`

I have seen answers suggesting to change `sudoers`, etc. but I am wondering if something more like what I said is possible.

Comment: That would be horrible, as then the password would then be exposed e.g. to `ps(1)` that any user on the system might snoop on.

Comment: cant you run the script as root and avoid that? from within /etc/rc.d/ for example

Comment: Run the entire script under `sudo` so you only need to provide the password once, when you start the script. If you don't want to provide a password at all, update the question to say so.

Comment: It's in autostart, more specifically, one command in a .desktop file

Comment: if it's a single command your best bet is to give permissions to run only that command using sudo without a password

Answer (score 0):

Running your startup script with sudo wouldn't make any sense.  `sudo` is for running commands that require root privileges as a regular user without needing to login as root.  It's not meant for startup scripts, that's what systemd or init.d scripts are for.

A relatively easy solution would be to add your script to the root user's crontab like so:

`sudo crontab -e`

Add this line:

`@reboot /path/to/your/script.sh`

This will run at startup as the root user, bypassing any need for interactive authentication.